# How can i create a Partial View for MVC4 or MVC 5 using Entity Framework (.edmx Model) with Razor Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to create a partial view on my home controller from a `.edmx` model.

I cannot change the properties of this model because it is a part of another system that I am building this Website around.

I have spent a very long time trying to work this out and have came here to hopefully get some help and advice.

**Aim:** Render a partial `_Patient.cshtml` view on the Homepage using models in an `.edmx` model.  I would like for you to show me where I have gone wrong as it does not work.

**What is the problem?**

**I get multiple errors such as:**

> model: : EntityType model has no key defined. Define the key for this entity type.
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Models', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`
>
> using the generic type 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable requires 1 type arguments MVC

Currently I'm getting this **error**  but I get the feeling that it's at the front of a long list of them.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel]'.

Below is the **.edmx**
(as I cannot post images yet..

**User** (edmx)
-Properties-
UserID
CodeName
UseBriefInstructions
Device_DeviceID
-Navigation Properties-
Device
RegimeItems

**Device**
-Properties-
DeviceID
Name
-Navigation Properties-
Users

**Session**
-Properties-
SessionID
ActiveUserID
ActiveDeviceID
StartedAt
ReachedFinish
-Navigation Properties-
SessionExcercises

(the Edmx is alot bigger than shown however these are the models that i currently need to use. however session and user are infact linked through another model)

**HomeController.cs**

```
using FaceToFaceWebsite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public F2FDataEntities _db = F2FDataEntities();

        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Long", VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null, int page = 1)
        //public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model =
            _db.UserID.ToList()
            .OrderByDescending(u =>u.UserID)
            .Take(10)
            .Select (u => new PatientListViewModel
             {
                  CodeName = u.CodeName,
                  Name = u.Name
             }).ToPagedList(page, 10);

            return PartialView("_Patient", new FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel());
            ////return View(model);


            ////ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Patients()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Help()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Contact Us";
            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_db != null)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

}
```

**PatientListViewModel**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class PatientListViewModel
    {
        public virtual ICollection<User> CodeName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Session> ReachedFinish { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Device> Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientHomeViewModel>*@

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }
    @Html.Partial("_Patient", Model)
```

**Views/Home/_Patient.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<PatientListViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h4>UserID: @item.CodeName</h4>
        <span>Finished: @item.ReachedFinish</span>
        <p>Machine: @item.Name</p>
        <hr />
    </div>

}
```

**PatientProfile.cs (i tried making another model to as a different approach but to no success)**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    
    namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
    {
        public class PatientProfile : DbContext
        {
           public PatientProfile() : base("F2FDataEntities")
            {
    
            }
           public DbSet<User> UserID { get; set; }
           public DbSet<Device> Name { get; set; }
            //public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    
            public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel> PatientListViewModels { get; set; } 
        }
    }
```

**F2FDataDB.cs(I Tried creating another Db that would use the models from the edmx)**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    
    namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
    {
        public class F2FDataEntities : DbContext 
        {
            public F2FDataEntities() : base("name=F2FDataEntities")
            {
            }
    
            public DbSet<User> UserID { get; set; }
            public DbSet<User>CodeName { get; set; }
            //public DbSet<Session> SessionDB { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Device> Name { get; set; }
    
            public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel> PatientListViewModel { get; set; }
        }    
    }
```

I've posted everything i see as relevant, if you need anymore information please let me know.
I apologise if the solution is simple, im new to MVC and this problem has gone on for quite some time.

**---------UPDATE 2.0-------------
Views/home/index.cshtml**

```
@model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

@Html.Partial("_Patient", Model.PatientProfile)

**views/shared/_Patient.cshtml (partial view)**

```
@model List<PatientProfile>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h4>UserID: @item.CodeName</h4>
        <div>
            @*<span>UserName: @item.CodeName</span>*@
        </div>
        @*<span>Started Session at: @item.StartedAt</span>*@
        <span>Finished: @item.ReachedFinish</span>
        <p>Machine: @item.Name</p>
        <hr />
    </div>

}
```

**patientlistviewmodel.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class PatientListViewModel
    {

        public List<Patient> PatientProfile { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patient
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string CodeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public F2FDataEntities _db = new F2FDataEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new PatientListViewModel();
            viewModel.PatientProfile = new List<Patient>();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

**Models/PatientProfile.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    
    public class PatientProfile : DbContext
    {
       public PatientProfile() : base("F2FDataEntities")
        {

        }
       public DbSet<User> UserID { get; set; }
       public DbSet<User> CodeName{ get; set; }
       public DbSet<Device> Name { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Session> ReachedFinish { get; set; }
       
    }
    
}
```

I am currently getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.Patient]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type

**I am getting this error at "..@Html.Partial("_patient", Model.PatientProfile)"**

**_Patient (Partial view)**

```
@model List<PatientProfile>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h4>UserID: @item.CodeName</h4>
        <span>Finished: @item.ReachedFinish</span>
        <p>Machine: @item.Name</p>
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: apologies, i changed the title to address that.

Comment: No, please update your question body with your actual question. It is unclear what exactly you're asking of us. What is the problem? What do you expect it to do, what does it do and why not?

Comment: As far as I can see, you have created a partial view `_Patient.cshtml`.
But it doesn't explain what you are having trouble with. Can you please explain the problem you are having, in detail.

Comment: Hopefully that is a little more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.**

You are passing back the PartialView as a Result:

```
return PartialView("_Patient", new FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel());
```

Change this to return `View(model);` In your Index function. This will return your Home Page `"Views/Home/Index.cshtml"`, and in this Index view you have:

```
@Html.Partial("_Patient", Model)
```

Which will Render the Partial View. But you are passing the wrong Model to your Index View: in Controller you are passing `PatientListViewModel`But in you index you have: `IEnumerable<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientHomeViewModel>`.

So either you pass `IEnumerable<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientHomeViewModel>`,

like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
return PartialView(new FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel());
}
```

And then you can call Partial View like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientHomeViewModel>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }


    @Html.Partial("_Patient", Model)
```

2. **What you should do.**

   **Controller:**

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var viewModel = PatientListViewModel();
       viewModel.PatientList = new List<Patients>();
       viewModel.CustomerList = new List<Cusotmer>();
       return View(viewModel);
   }
   ```

**Index.cshtml**

```
        @model PatientListViewModel

    @* Considering your partial view is in Shared Foler*@

// Note Passing the Correct Model to Partial View

        @Html.Partial("_Patient", Model.PatientsList)

// Another Example:

    @Html.Partial("_Customer", Model.CustomerList)
```

Your **_Patient.cshtml (partial View)**

```
@model List<PatientsList>

@foreach(var item in Model){
item.Name

}
```

Your **_Customer.cshtml (partial View)** // Another Example

```
@model List<Custom>

@foreach(var item in Model){
item.Name

}
```

**Your ViewModel:**

```
public class PatientListViewModel{

public List<Patient> PatientsList {get;set;}
public List<Customer> CustomerList{get;set;}
}

public class Patient{
public string Name {get;set;
}
// Another Example
public Class Customer{
public string Name{get;set;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    @model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        }

    // PatientListViewModel this is the Name of you class
    // To Access your Model you always have to use Model. Not the Class Name
// PatientListViewModel is the Class name
// Model is the Object --> You passed from Controller.
// Use Model.PatientProfile
// Not PatientListViewModel.PatientProfile
    @Html.Partial("_Patient", Model.PatientProfile)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help so far :)


With the HomeController i cam getting an error with the "PatientListViewModel" saying it is "a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

for the "List" i am getting "Using the generic type @system.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type argument".

I also apologise for PatientHomeViewController, that was a mistake i did not correct.  It should have been PatientListViewModel.

Comment: This code is not tested in Visual Studio, I typed in StackOverflow.
var viewModel = PatientListViewModel(); should be
var viewModel = new PatientListViewModel();

Comment: Thanks!  what about "viewModel.PatientProfile = new List();"  i am getting "Using the generic type @system.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type argument" with that.

Comment: viewModel.PatientProfile = new List<YOURCLASSNAME>();

Comment: viewModel.PatientProfile  = new List<PatientProfile >();

Comment: Thankyou, i am now getting an error i had last week which is. "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel]'."

Comment: Are you getting when Rendering PartialView? or the Index?

Comment: Change this: @model IEnumerable<FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientHomeViewModel>
to FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientHomeViewModel in Index

Comment: i tried that, and it runs without errors, then...

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.PatientListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

Comment: what's the Model in the Partial View now?

Comment: @model List<PatientProfile>  which consists of...namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    
    public class PatientProfile : DbContext
    {
       public PatientProfile() : base("F2FDataEntities")
        {

        }
       public DbSet<User> UserID { get; set; }
       public DbSet<User> CodeName{ get; set; }
       public DbSet<Device> Name { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Session> ReachedFinish { get; set; }
       
    }
    
}

Comment: As I explained in my answer you have to pass the correct Model to the Views and Partial Views which you are not doing. Please read my examples i gave. You have to pass a LIST<PATIENTPROFILE>, in @Html.Partial("_Patient", HERE), LIKE THIS --> @Html.Partial("_Partial", Model.PatientProfile) NOT @Html.Partial("_Partial", Model)

Comment: Sorry about this, i know it must be fustrating.  When i do that i get Error: "..Models.PatientListViewModel is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'  I get that with both PatientProfile and  PatientListViewModel.

Comment: post the code where you are loading @Html.Partial in your qeustion

Comment: @Html.Partial("_Patient", Model.PatientProfile) Not the Class name:
PatientListViewModel == WRONG
Model == RIGHT

Comment: If i use @Html.Partial("_Patient", Model.PatientProfile) i get... An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.Patient]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type ....

I will post the _Patient,Index, HomeController, and patient profile in the Question .

Comment: In your Partial view you have: model List<PatientProfile>
And in your ViewModel you have: List<Patient>, 
Change your PartialView to have: 
@model List<Patient> OR your ViewModel to Have: public List<PatientProfile> PatitentProfile {get;set;}